# Flash animation for my textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have set up a textblock to set the string "ALARM" added to it when the alrm clock goes off. The code is working fine for this process. I am trying to make this string "ALARM" (or the textblock itself) flash when the alarm goes off.

I am able to work out the codes to make the string "ALARM" fade in fade out using mouse events but cant figure out how to make it happen w/o the need for mouse events. I tried textBlock_Loaded event and that doesn't work. I want the fade in fade out to be ongoing forever in a loop to create a flashing effect.

Please advice if there is an event that would fit my need. Been trying one by one down the list of available events with no success. My codes for the mouse events is below. Appreciate any advice. Thanks.

```
private void textBlock3_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textblk = (TextBlock)sender;
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    textblk.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.OpacityProperty, animation);
}

private void textBlock3_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textblk = (TextBlock)sender;
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    textblk.BeginAnimation(TextBlock.OpacityProperty, animation);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is an `EventTrigger` with the "Loaded" event.  Set the `RepeatBehavior` to "Forever" so that the Storyboard keeps repeating, and `AutoReverse` to "True":

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Text="hello world">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     Duration="0:0:1"
                                     To="0"
                                     />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Hi the animation works but it kind of jams up the application. I had textboxes in which I could enter numbers. When I include this set of codes, I am no longer am able to input anything inside those textboxes. Also unable to click on my buttons.

Comment: Scratch that, it was cos of my own syntax error. Thanks for help.